# How to save List<List<Object>> list to Shared Preferences Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, persistence

I have this list:

```
List<List<GraphInfo>> list = [
  [
    GraphInfo(title: 'Graph 1', xAxis: "10", yAxis: "15"),
    GraphInfo(title: 'Graph 1', xAxis: "15", yAxis: "20"),
  ],
  [
    GraphInfo(title: 'Graph 2', xAxis: "20", yAxis: "20"),
    GraphInfo(title: 'Graph 2', xAxis: "25", yAxis: "25"),
  ],
];
```

Which I need to display a graph in my app (and it has to be a List inside a List).

And I need to find a way to save the list locally.

I have tried using **Sqlite, Hive and Shared Preferences** but no luck, as it is difficult to persist a List with a custom object.

GraphInfo class:

```
class GraphInfo {
  int? id;
  String title;
  String xAxis;
  String yAxis;

  GraphInfo({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.xAxis,
    required this.yAxis,
  });

  factory GraphInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return GraphInfo(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        xAxis: json["xAxis"],
        yAxis: json["yAxis"]);
  }

  factory GraphInfo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => GraphInfo(
        id: map["id"]?.toInt() ?? 0,
        title: map["title"] ?? '',
        xAxis: map["xAxis"] ?? '',
        yAxis: map["yAxis"] ?? '',
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "id": id,
      "title": title,
      "xAxis": xAxis,
      "yAxis": yAxis,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '{name: $title, x: $xAxis, y: $yAxis}';
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas to save this list? (They can include Sqlite, Hive and Shared Preferences).

Please do not hesitate to enquire further.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have everything needed to serialize/deserialize your data.

### Serialize

```dart
Future<void> addToSP(List<List<GraphInfo>> tList) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('graphLists', jsonEncode(tList));
}
```

### Deserialize

```dart
void getSP() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final List<dynamic> jsonData =
      jsonDecode(prefs.getString('graphLists') ?? '[]');
  list = jsonData.map<List<GraphInfo>>((jsonList) {
    return jsonList.map<GraphInfo>((jsonItem) {
      return GraphInfo.fromJson(jsonItem);
    }).toList();
  }).toList();
  setState(() {});
}
```

## Full code sample

[image]

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// PRESENTATION LAYER

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
        ),
      ),
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<List<GraphInfo>> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    addToSP(defaultList).then((_) => getSP());
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> addToSP(List<List<GraphInfo>> tList) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('graphLists', jsonEncode(tList));
  }

  void getSP() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final List<dynamic> jsonData =
        jsonDecode(prefs.getString('graphLists') ?? '[]');
    list = jsonData.map<List<GraphInfo>>((jsonList) {
      return jsonList.map<GraphInfo>((jsonItem) {
        return GraphInfo.fromJson(jsonItem);
      }).toList();
    }).toList();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return list.isNotEmpty
        ? Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: list.map((subList) {
                return subList.isNotEmpty
                    ? Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: subList.map((x) => Text(x.title)).toList(),
                      )
                    : const Text('Empty subList');
              }).toList(),
            ),
          )
        : const Text('NOTHING');
  }
}

// MODEL

class GraphInfo {
  int? id;
  String title;
  String xAxis;
  String yAxis;

  GraphInfo({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.xAxis,
    required this.yAxis,
  });

  factory GraphInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return GraphInfo(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        xAxis: json["xAxis"],
        yAxis: json["yAxis"]);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "id": id,
      "title": title,
      "xAxis": xAxis,
      "yAxis": yAxis,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '{name: $title, x: $xAxis, y: $yAxis}';
}

// DATA

final List<List<GraphInfo>> defaultList = [
  [
    GraphInfo(title: 'Graph 1', xAxis: "10", yAxis: "15"),
    GraphInfo(title: 'Graph 1', xAxis: "15", yAxis: "20"),
  ],
  [
    GraphInfo(title: 'Graph 2', xAxis: "20", yAxis: "20"),
    GraphInfo(title: 'Graph 2', xAxis: "25", yAxis: "25"),
  ],
];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Your code works as expected but I then need to assign decodedList to list. I have used Shared preferences. Can you take a look at my code? `void addToSP(List<List<GraphInfo>> tList) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.clear();
    String encodedList = jsonEncode(tList);
    print(encodedList);
    await prefs.setString('graphLists', encodedList);
  }`

Comment: `void getSP() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? encodedList = prefs.getString('graphLists');
    final decodedList = jsonDecode(encodedList!).map((l) {
      return l.map((item) => GraphInfo.fromMap(item)).toList();
    }).toList();
    //print(decodedList[0][0]);
    setState(() {
      list = decodedList;
    });
  }` .I get this exception: **Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<GraphInfo>>'**

Comment: It doesn't manage to identify the typing of your `decodedList`, you should type the `map` operation. I updated my answer with a full code sample.